# В VS Code нет импорта из папок и файлов в проекте Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, импорт

В VS Code создан проект на Python. При подключенном виртуальном окружении и выбранном интерпретаторе в veny/Script импорт библиотек происходит нормально, а импорт из соседних папок и рядом лежащих файлов не получается. Например, в главном файле в корне для соседнего файла settings импорт переменной settings в виде from settings import settings выдает ошибку Import "settings" could not be resolvedPylance. Такая же ситуация при импорте из папки в корне from handlers.basic import get_start. Помогите найти причину такого поведения.

Comment: Попробуйте `from . import settings`

Comment: Относительные пути работают, но я хочу разобраться, почему не работают абсолютные пути.

Comment: Я думаю (не знаю!), что вероятнее всего это связано с особенностями запуска через VS. Он можешь не 'открывать' файл, а запускать саму венву, и из неё уже вызывать файл. Тогда абсолютные пути будут относительно венвы. Это только предположение, но я не могу это иначе объяснить.